# MySQL LEFT JOIN a ON b compared to including WHERE a IN (b)

Tags: mysql

When I run the following query I get 2769 rows returned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.account_id = t1.account_id;
```

However, when I add the WHERE clause below, I get 692 Lines returned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.account_id = t1.account_id
WHERE t2.account_id IN (t1.account_id);
```

I thought that the condition established by my LEFT JOIN would the same condition established by my WHERE clause (i.e. that these two lines would effectively be redundant).

This is clearly not the case, but I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left join` returns all records of `t1` and returns `null` for the columns of `t2` for all records where the join could not be made.

But the  `where` clause filters all data, no matter from which table. So when you filter on `t2` in your `where` clause then all records where the join could not be made (and the `t2.account_id` is `null`) get excluded from the result since `null != t1.account_id`.

So basically your  `where` clause turn your `left join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: That makes sense of what I'm seeing on my end perfectly. Thank you for the assistance!